# Definition explanation: Definition of point of a set in category theory

Tags: category-theory, definition

I just started studying category theory using the book: "Conceptual Mathematics" by F. WILLIAM LAWVERE and STEPHEN H. SCHANUEL and there's one thing that I can't understand. In the first chapter, before the author gives the definition of a Category he gives the example of the category of finite sets and maps between those sets.

At some point during the example he gives the following definition:

> Fix a set singleton set denoted as $1$. Then a point of a set $X$ is a map $1\to X$.

I'll set up a little example so I can explain what got me confused about this definition.

---

Let $X$ be the set $\{$a, b, c$\}$. Here a,b,c are just letters and not variables representing something.

1. If we fix a singleton set $1$, then there are $3$ maps from $1$ to $X$. They only say that a point is a map from $1 \to X$ but they never specify what map, so I suppose that the point "a" is the map that associates the only element of $1$ to "a". Is this correct?
2. Are the elements of the set $X$ and the points of the set $X$ the same thing? Is a point an element of the set?
   If this is the case and the set $X$ is a collection of those points (this is, the collection of maps $1\to X$), then what we are doing is defining a point using the definition of point: We are defining a point as a function from $1$ to a set of other points. So it makes sense that the set $X$ has its elements: "a,b,c" and then there are also the points "a", "b" and "c".
3. There are infinite singleton sets that we can choose as our set $1$. Does that mean that each point has an infinite amount of ways it can be represented as functions? Or if $1$ and $1'$ are different singleton sets, and if $1\to X$ and $1'\to X$ are two functions that map the element of the singleton set to "a", does that count as just one point (the point "a"), or as two separate points?

Thank you.

Comment: The point behind the definition is that in category theory we (mostly) speak about a category in terms of its objects and its arrows. To interpret a point in a set as an arrow from a singleton into this set allows us to forget about the internal structure of the set and speak of its elements as arrows which can be generalized to other categories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. If you introduce the notation $a\in X$ for "a is an element of the set $X$", then $a\in X$ is synonymous with "for all singleton sets $\{*\}$, there is a morphism $f\colon \{*\}\to X$ with $f(*)=a$. So, no, the elements of a set and the points of a set are not the same thing. But, they are in a bijective correspondence. And no, a point is (typically) not an element. The thing to notice here is that in order to speak of the element $a\in X$ we must introduce the notation $\in$. But in order to speak of a point $X$ (in the sense given in the book), we do not need to introduce anything new. All we have is the category of sets, and a point is defined in categorical terms. If the definition of the category of sets can be given without using $\in$ in any way, then we obtain a way of reasoning about sets without ever using $\in$ (this can be done, in a clever way).
3. Correct, each point has many different presentations, one for each choice of the actual set $1$. All of these presentations are canonically 'the same'. Instead of identifying them, we simply let all of them coexist in peace. We simply remember that a point is a morphism $1\to X$, where $1$ is some fixed singleton. It really doesn't matter which one (or which $1$) it is.

Comment: This was so helpful, Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.